# JAX-RS standard solution for serialize arrays of one element

Tags: jax-rs

Like it is described in jersey documentation, jersey use as default MAPPED notation, so I have a serialization problem with lists of one element.

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e949

Until now, I resolved the problem in the client side, but now, I don't have access to client code.

I need serialize arrays in NATURAL notation, but i can't make me code dependent of jersey. I need a solution according to JAX-RS standards, a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JAX-RS, don't specify JSON provider, so i must implement my own provider if i want a portable solution.